# Power Query Editor - Import .Parquet File

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, parquet, m

How can I convert an imported .parquet file correctly, using Excel's Power Query Editor?

Are there drivers available for this in Excel?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the inbuilt connector in Power BI:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/parquet

```
let
    Source = Parquet.Document(File.Contents("C:\xxx\userdata1.parquet"), [Compression=null, LegacyColumnNameEncoding=false, MaxDepth=null])
in
    Source
```

In Excel, I believe you need a 3rd party connector.

https://www.cdata.com/drivers/parquet/excel/

Comment: Okay, noted.

cdata's Excel Parquet Drivers are very expensive. 
Will have to make another plan to convert my data to .csv in Azure Data Storage  for online retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

You could use DuckDB as well (ODBC Connection)

it’s much faster than any other solution.

DuckDB also allows you to combine multiple Parquet files by writing your own SELECT statement.

It’s super easy.

Check it out here https://erpl.io/blog/connect-excel-to-parquet/